# How to setup connection to the SQL Server for my ASP.NET MVC with EF application

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm very new to setting up a SQL Server database and connecting to it (Visual Studio 2012 for Web). I've downloaded SQL Server 2014 and I have SQL Server (Express) running in my services.

I'm clueless as to what my next step should be, I've setup a data connection in the Database Explorer view using the SQL Server Express but when I try to `update-database` in my Package Manager Console I get

> The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance

which could be because my connection string is wrong.

Connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RecreationalServices;Integrated Security=False" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

[Check IMAGE CLICK HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHSHO.png)

Error code in full text

```
PM> update-database
```

> No pending code-based migrations.
>   System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance. ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a version hint is required.
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlVersionUtils.GetSqlVersion(String versionHint)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderManifest..ctor(String manifestToken)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifest(String versionHint)
>   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String manifestToken)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifest(String manifestToken)
>   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.InitializeProviderManifest(Action`3 addError)
>
>   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.OnProviderManifestTokenNotification(String token, Action`3 addError)
>   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleProviderManifestTokenAttribute(XmlReader reader)
>   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleAttribute(XmlReader reader)
>   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.ParseAttribute(XmlReader reader)
>   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.Parse(XmlReader reader)
>   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleTopLevelSchemaElement(XmlReader reader)
>   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.InternalParse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
>   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
>   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection)
>
>   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths)
>
>   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
>   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Extensions.XDocumentExtensions.GetStoreItemCollection(XDocument model, DbProviderInfo& providerInfo)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.EdmModelDiffer.Diff(XDocument sourceModel, XDocument targetModel, String connectionString)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.IsModelOutOfDate(XDocument model, DbMigration lastMigration)
>
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.RunCore()
>          at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.Run()
>       The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance.

Comment: If `IntegratedSecurity` is false you must supply `User Id` and `Password` attributes.

Comment: There are lot of tutorial for this. Just google it for `mvc ef tutorial`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Of course I know how to google. Most of them want you to use a local database first which I don't want to do.

Comment: @Crowcoder IntegratedSercurity doesn't work. Where do i enter the userID and password? I don't think I have any

Comment: I didnt say you dont know how to google. I say instead of asking us to teach you how work with EF, you should be following a tutorial first. Then when you have a problem you can ask. Also you say you dont want use a local db and that is the one you are using?  Check this one https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ for every string connection. Did you try connect from SQL Studio first?

Comment: @Crowcoder I added the database using enable-migrations -contexttypename IssueContext and I'm the same user. The funny thing is that I thought the connection string would be provided like it was in the image.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I'm not asking you to teach me how to work with EF. I'm asking if someone could verify that the connection string provided in the Database Explorer is the one I'm suppose to copy if you actually clicked on the image.

Comment: Did you try it? Or want us try it for you first? If doesnt work is you use the wrong one. Again, the first thing you learn from the tutorials is connect to db. If you cant connect then you need to learn from scratch. And if you follow a basic tutorial you will know there is a wizard to create the connection string for you. So you dont even have to worried about that. But you probably know everything already

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza How can you try it for me? Do you have my access to my SQL server or do you know my logins? Before you post could you please post something constructive instead of being condescending? I've tried it and obviously it didn't work or I would've upvoted your comment or told you it worked. I am following a asp.net mvc tutorial but it uses a localdb to store data while I want to use a SQL server. I've told you time and time again the connection string was provided from Visual Studio if you actually looked at the image.

Comment: I dont try to be condescendent. I m telling you are asking the wrong question. Following the tutorial, use the wizards and create the context, if you cant then the server is down or the password is wrong. I havent wrote a connection string in years EF always do it for me.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza 2 people are not having any issues with my question so I don't know what's your problem with it. That's why I'm asking if the connection string provided by EF is the one I use hence the image. If you are continuing to tell me to use google then refrain from posting please.

Comment: Did you add a migration first? "enable-migrations", then "add-migration InitialSetup" then "update-database -Verbose".

Comment: @SteveGreene I first used `enable-migrations -contexttypename IssueContext` then `add-migration InitialCreate` then `update-database` There was a small error when i used `add-migration InitialCreate` but I fixed it(One of my classes wasn't referenced)

Comment: Is your context in a separate project? Is that project selected in the package manager console? Otherwise try update-database -contexttypename IssueContext

Comment: @SteveGreene So this kind of worked. I enabled pipeline in my SQL Server Configuration Manager and then I deleted my _Migration History table in my database. Deleted my Migration folder and did `enable-migrations -contexttypename IssueContext`  `migration InitialCreate`then `update-database  ` the it spit out this `There is already an object named 'Administrator' in the database.` Can I delete every table in the Database and redo the steps in SQL Server Object Explorer?

Comment: That's because on the first migration there is nothing to compare to so it tries to recreate all the objects. You need to add a baseline migration that takes a snapshot of your existing objects: "add-migration InitialCreate -IgnoreChanges" The ignore changes tells EF to just take a snapshot and not to try and recreate everything. Now your next migration will just be the model changes.

Comment: @Steve Greene I deleted the whole database and did the migration. I haven't used `update-database` because there's an error. Is it normal for all the tables to be null? Does it only populate my database when I use `update-database`?

Comment: update-database will run your migration and create empty tables (the first time). If you want them populated you can override the Seed() method in the migration. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3

Comment: @SteveGreene I see why my tables aren't populated. I have the Seed() method finished but I have this error which prevents me from updating. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35761285/mvc-with-ef-relational-database-mapping

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Integrated Security from False to True.

Comment: Did you get another exception info or still the same?

Comment: Exactly the same one. I've either not connected to the SQL Server or my connection string is wrong.

Comment: Probably your SQL server is not started. Go to Windows Services panel and make sure that "SQL Server" service is started. See link bellow: http://clip2net.com/s/3v5dYtn

Comment: @MaxymVoronitskiy In the picture the server looks ok.

Comment: But it is is my local server. I sent a picture as a sample how it should be.

Comment: @Maxym Voronitskiy Yes the service "SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) "has started. Don't worry I know what you are talking about. I even followed a video to verify that my server name is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the wizard to create the model like this example http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4b0136/getting-started-with-wizard-in-Asp-Net-mvc-5-part-1/

Comment: I'm actually following this one http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application but they use a localdb instead of a sql server