# MVC with EF Relational Database Mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relational-database

I have this error when I try to update my database to population my tables.

PM> update-database

```
No pending explicit migrations.
Running Seed method.
System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at RecreationServicesTicketingSystem.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(IssueContext context) in C:\Users\jwan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RecreationServicesTicketingSystem\RecreationServicesTicketingSystem\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 60
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Sequence contains no matching element
```

I'm been googling around and no one seems to have a similar issue. It's on this Line `var administrator = new List<Administrator>` I put in a pointer as to where line 60 is.

[Click Here Tables from SQL Server Management Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nwgm.png)

[Click Here for Entity Models](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BnJX.jpg)

```
 public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }
    protected override void Seed(RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext context)
    {

        var departments = new List<Department>
        {
            new Department { DepartmentID = 1, Name = "IT"},
            new Department { DepartmentID = 2, Name = "Admin" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 3, Name = "Human Resources"},
            new Department { DepartmentID = 4, Name = "Mechanics" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 5, Name = "Directors" },
            new Department { DepartmentID = 6, Name = "Operations"}

        };
        departments.ForEach(s => context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
        context.SaveChanges();


        var depots = new List<Depot>
        {
            new Depot { DepotID = 1, Name = "Porana"},
            new Depot { DepotID = 2, Name = "Far North"},


        };
        departments.ForEach(s => context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

    var users = new List<User>
{
    new User { FirstMidName = "Jason",   LastName = "Wan",
        EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1},
    new User { FirstMidName = "Andy", LastName = "Domagas",
        EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1,DepotID = 1},
    new User { FirstMidName = "Denis",   LastName = "Djohar",
        EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1 ,DepotID = 1},
    new User { FirstMidName = "Christine",   LastName = "West",
        EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentID = 1, DepotID = 1},

};

        var administrator = new List<Administrator> <-- LINE 60
        {
            new Administrator {AdminID = 1, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL1", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 1),
            Tickets = new List<Ticket>() },
            new Administrator {AdminID = 2, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL2", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 2),
            Tickets = new List<Ticket>() },
            new Administrator {AdminID = 3, AdminRole = "Administrator LVL3", User = users.Single ( s => s.UserID == 3),
            Tickets = new List<Ticket>() }

        };
        administrator.ForEach(s => context.Administrators.AddOrUpdate(p => p.AdminID, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var categories = new List<Category>
        {
            new Category {CategoryID = 0001, Title = "Desktop"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0002, Title = "Mobile"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0003, Title = "Menzits"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0004, Title = "XMPRO"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0005, Title = "Con-X"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0006, Title = "Promapp"},
            new Category {CategoryID = 0007, Title = "QGIS"},
        };
        categories.ForEach(s => context.Categories.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Title, s));
        context.SaveChanges();

        var tickets = new List<Ticket>
        {
            new Ticket {
                UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
                CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Con-X" ).CategoryID,
                Issue = ("Test Error 1"),
                Priority = Priority.High
            },
            new Ticket {
                UserID = users.Single(s => s.LastName == "Wan").UserID,
                CategoryID = categories.Single(c => c.Title == "Desktop" ).CategoryID,
                Issue = ("Test Error 2"),
                Priority = Priority.Med
            },
        };


        foreach (Ticket e in tickets)
        {
            var ticketInDataBase = context.Tickets.Where(
                s =>
                    s.User.UserID == e.UserID &&
                    s.Category.CategoryID == e.CategoryID).SingleOrDefault();
            if (ticketInDataBase == null)
            {
                context.Tickets.Add(e);
            }
        }
        context.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

User.cs

```
public class User
    {

        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]

        [Column("FirstName")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        public string FullName
        {
            get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
        }
        public int AdministratorID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("AdministratorID")]
        public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }

        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }


        public int DepotID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("DepotID")]
        public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }

        public int TicketID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Users { get; set; }

    }
```

Department.cs

```
public class Department
{

    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Depot.cs

```
public class Depot
{

    public int DepotID { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating your users you are not specifying the department they belong to, this means for an int field that by default it will be 0. There is no department in your database with id 0 therefore the foreign key constraint is violated.
Try something like:

```
var users = new List<User>
        {
            new User { FirstMidName = "Jason",   LastName = "Wan",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentId = 1 },
            new User { FirstMidName = "Andy", LastName = "Domagas",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentId = 1 },
            new User { FirstMidName = "Denis",   LastName = "Djohar",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentId = 1 },
            new User { FirstMidName = "Christine",   LastName = "West",
                EnrollmentDate = DateTime.Parse("2016-02-18"), DepartmentId = 1 },

        };
```

Update to solve the depot issue:

You are creating the depots, however the line that adds them to the context is referencing departments instead of depots:

```
 var depots = new List<Depot>
        {
            new Depot { DepotID = 1, Name = "Porana"},
            new Depot { DepotID = 2, Name = "Far North"},


        };
        departments.ForEach(s => context.Departments.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));// should be:
        depots.ForEach(s => context.Depots.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes that solved the department problem THANK YOU and now I have the exact same error but it talks about depotID. I applied the same concept but it's not correct. `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.User_dbo.Depot_DepotID". The conflict occurred in database "RecreationalServicesTicketingSystem.DAL.IssueContext", table "dbo.Depot", column 'DepotID'.` Check my question for the updated version.

Comment: Doesn't look like you are creating any depots, make sure to create them before referencing them in your user

Comment: Don't worry! I made a silly mistake `depots.ForEach(s => context.Depots.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s));` I put in departments instead of depot. Now i have this `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element`

Comment: does it tell you where it occurs?

Comment: Line 60 `var administrator = new List<Administrator>`

Comment: it might be because you are not saving your users to the context, so now you are trying to AddOrUpdate administrator but the user object is not part of the context.

Comment: add users.ForEach(s => context.Users.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, s)); context.SaveChanges();

Comment: Where abouts? Under Department and Depot? Why do we need p.Name?

Comment: Under user, you will need to add the properties for the user in the lambda

Comment: Sorry bad copy pasting

Comment: I would suggest starting a new question for it to get a better answer, the initial problem here is solved, this is a new problem and it deserves a new question, so that other people with similar problems can find an easy answer

Comment: It's over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35762425/mvc-conflicting-changes-detected-mvc-ef